# How do I write dig output to /etc/hosts file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, hosts, dig

I'm a shell beginner and here's an example, I don't know how to implement it.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Step 1: Get the domain resolution A record via `dig`.

```
dig @8.8.8.8 liveproduseast.akamaized.net +short | tail -n1
```

Step 2: Form the obtained IP address and domain name into a line that looks like this.

```
23.1.236.106 liveproduseast.akamaized.net
```

Step 3: Add it to the last line of the `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1  localhost loopback
::1        localhost
23.1.236.106 liveproduseast.akamaized.net
```

Step 4: Set it up to automate the task and run it every 6 hours. When the parsing IP has changed, update it to the `/etc/hosts` file (replacing the previously added IP).

```
crontab -e
6 * * * * /root/test.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is basically replacing the old ip with the new one:

```bsh
$ cat /root/test.sh
#!/bin/sh

current_ip=$(awk '/liveproduseast.akamaized.net/ {print $1}' /etc/hosts)
new_ip=$(dig @8.8.8.8 liveproduseast.akamaized.net +short | tail -n1 | grep '^[.0-9]*$')

[[ -z $new_ip ]] && exit

if sed "s/$current_ip/$new_ip/" /etc/hosts > /tmp/etchosts; then
    cat /tmp/etchosts > /etc/hosts
    rm /tmp/etchosts
fi
```

On the sed part, if you're using GNU you can simply do:

```
sed -i "s/$current_ip/$new_ip/" /etc/hosts
```

Or if you have `moreutils` installed

```
sed "s/$current_ip/$new_ip/" /etc/hosts | sponge /etc/hosts
```

---

### Explanation

`grep '^[.0-9]*$'` catches IP address, if there isn't one, then it outputs nothing.

```
awk '/liveproduseast.akamaized.net/ {print $1}' /etc/hosts
```

Find a line which contains exactly "liveproduseast.akamaized.net", then grab its first column, which is the IP.

```
sed "s/what to replace/replacement/" file
```

Replace the first occurrence of what you want to replace with the replacement value

And for notice, you cannot do:

```
sed "s/what to replace/replacement/" file > file
```

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t

Comment: There are two problems with this: it only adds the IP address and no domain name. Also in future updates it will add records repeatedly instead of replacing the IP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the hostname is fixed.

Comment: Run error "sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression", /etc/hosts has become an empty file, is there something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108693/discussion-between-annahri-and-matthew).